# Reading a specific line from large file in Perl

Tags: perl, file, line

Is there any fast and memory efficient way to read specific lines of large file, without loading it to memory?

I wrote a perl script, that runs many forks and I would like them to read specific lines from a file.

At the moment Im using an external command:

```
sub getFileLine {
    my ( $filePath, $lineWanted ) = @_;
    $SIG{PIPE} = '_IGNORE_';
    open( my $fh, '-|:utf8', "tail -q -n +$lineWanted \"$filePath\" | head -n 1" );
    my $line = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
    chomp( $line );
    return $line;
}
```

Its fast and it works - but maybe there's a more "Perl-ish" way, as fast and as memory efficient as this one?

As you know, creating a fork process in Perl duplicates the main process memory - so if the main process is using 10MB, the fork will use at least that much.

My goal is to keep fork process (so main process until running forks also) memory use as low as possible. Thats why I dont want to load the whole file into memory.

Comment: btw, it's `IGNORE`, not `_IGNORE_`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Before you go further, it's important to understand how `fork` works. When you `fork` a process, the OS uses [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) semantics to share the bulk of the parent and child processes' memory; only the amount of memory that differs between the parent and child need to  be separately allocated.

For reading a single line of a file in Perl, here's a simple way:

```
open my $fh, '<', $filePath or die "$filePath: $!";
my $line;
while( <$fh> ) {
    if( $. == $lineWanted ) { 
        $line = $_;
        last;
    }
}
```

This uses the special `$.` variable which holds the line number of the current filehandle.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at  [Tie::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html) core module.

Comment: I thought `Tie::File` was memory-inefficient. Didn't the OP request low memory usage?

Comment: @Zaid it's actually reasonably memory-efficient; it doesn't store the entire contents of the file in memory, only a list of *offsets* of each line. It's not free (even just the scalars to hold each offset take some space per line), but it's usually good enough to handle multi-hundred-megabyte files with ease.

Comment: @hobbs : Yup. I've looked at the documentation since then (comment is quite old now), and it makes it quite clear that it isn't a memory hog.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fork. As you can imagine, reading a specific line from a file is a common enough operation that one of the 20k modules on CPAN does it already.

[File::ReadBackwards](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aReadBackwards) is memory-efficient and fast.