# Perl - How extract file information for logrotate

Tags: perl, rotation

i have following list of application log files (rotated) and i would get only new lines generated. For do this operation i've think to extract **filename**, **inode** and **n. of rows** from each file, for write it into a temporally file, who i would read each time before my elaboration (*I am open to better solutions if you are*).

This is my list of files:

```
root> ls -l
applog_s0.0.log
applog_s0.1.log
applog_s0.2.log
applog_s0.3.log
applog_s1.0.log
applog_s1.1.log
applog_s1.2.log
applog_s1.3.log
applog_s2.0.log
applog_s2.1.log
applog_s2.2.log
applog_s2.3.log
applog_s3.0.log
applog_s3.1.log
applog_s3.2.log
applog_s3.3.log
```

I can't just read the last log file in order of number, because it may have closed recently and I risk data losing.

This is my draft of script (draft because some instruction return compiled errors):

```
my $MY_DIR="/usr/cataclust/sharedfolder/logs/";
my %filelist;

# Load file list
foreach my $filename (glob("$MY_DIR/applog_s*.log")) {
    my $ino = stat($filename);  # Get inode of my file
    my $nrows = $. ($filename); # this row doesn't work into script :( it works only by cmd line as perl -ne '}{ print $.' applog_s1.0.log 
    push( @{ $filelist { filename } }, $filename);
    push( @{ $filelist { inode } }, $ino);
    push( @{ $filelist { rows } }, $nrows);
}

# Elaborate log
foreach my $filename (glob("$IN_DIR/applog_s*.log")) {
    open (FILE, $filename) or die "can't read open $filename";
    $/ = "\n\n";
    while( <FILE> ) {
        my @rows = split /\n\n/;
        my $ino = stat($filename);
        if( $filename == $filelist{name} && $ino == $filelist{inode} ) {
        if( $. < $filelist{rows} ) { 
                my $rown = $.;
                if ($rows[$row] =~ m/\A\d.-\s(\d{8})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s-\s(\w+)\s-\s\/Extended Info/) {
                    if ($rows[$rown] =~ m/WARNING/ || $rows[$rown] =~ m/CRITICAL/ && $rows[$rown] !~ m/INFORMATION/) {  # Shows only errors
                        my ($date, $time, $class, $message ) = $rows[$rown] =~ m/\A\d.-\s(\d{8})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s-\s(\w+)\s-\s\/Extended Info\n(\w.*)/;
                        push @evt, {date => $date, time => $time, classification => $class, information => $message};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is log example:

```
0#- 20180403 11:11:11 - ERROR - /Extended Info
Fs Doesn't work...

1#- 20180403 11:12:13 - ERROR - /Extended Info
Fs Doesn't work...
```

could you help me to clarify?

Comment: `$.` is the current line number in the last accessed filehandle. Putting `($filename)` after it makes no sense.

Comment: @choroba i don't understand why perl -ne '}{ print $.' applog_s1.0.log works.....

Comment: @AllanSimeoe try to view this post, it could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551262/reading-a-specific-line-from-large-file-in-perl

Comment: @clarkseth yeah, i've seen this post, it's very useful for my thread, but i have to do a different thing in my script

Comment: Because `-n` loops over the file and `}{` or "eskimo greeting" introduces code executed when the loop ends.

Comment: @choroba thank you for training, now i know :) I try to find other solution on stack overflow posts

Comment: Maybe try breaking the problem into smaller steps and try asking for each one separately: How do I get the number of lines of a file? How do I get inode number of a file? etc. (Note that [stat](http://p3rl.org/stat) in scalar context doesn't return the inode number).

Comment: If you are just trying to see if the file has had more data appended then take the size of the file using the -s operator rather than trying to count lines